# HQL Query with like and or operators

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm using Hibernate, I want to get records based on like condition which contains or condition. It is something like this,

> from Employee where empno in (select empno from Employee where empname like 'A%' or 'B%' or 'C%' )"

Is it correct? Suggest me robust query..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for a subquery:

```
from Employee where empname like 'A%' or empname like 'B%' or empname like 'C%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a like statement for each condition in your where clause.  HQL will allow you to perform both in/like comparisons as well as subselects.

```
from Employee emp where emp.empno in 
(select emp2.empno from Employee emp2 where emp2.empname like 'A%' 
or emp2.empname like 'B%' or emp2.empname like 'C%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from Employee e 
    where e.empno in ( select ee.empno from Employee ee 
                       where ee.empname like 'A%' 
                       or ee.empname like 'B%' 
                       or ee.empname like 'C%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want more security and prevent sql injection, you can use createQuery with setParameter and wildcards like this:

```
@Override
public List<Employee> searchEmployee(String searchName) {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Query<Employee> searchQuery = currentSession.createQuery(
                    "from Employee where lower(empname ) like :theName or lower(empLlastName) like :theName", Employee.class);
searchQuery.setParameter("theName", "%" + searchName.toLowerCase() + "%");
List<Employee> employees = searchQuery.getResultList();
return employees;
}
```